# Use Primary Key to reference row for UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have a MySQL database which I'm trying to do an update or delete command with:

`$query = "UPDATE db SET this='$_POST[f_that]',this2='$_POST[f_that2]' WHERE index='$_POST[f_index]'";`

This returns a syntax error every time, saying the problem is near `index='#'`. The information comes from a table, which has input fields inline with the values set to the database (inline editing). The `form_index` is output in this fashion. Inside my database, the `index` is the primary key and auto incrementing.

I've `print_r()` the `$_POST` and the `$query` to make sure that the `form_index` is a number (and the right number at that), which it is.

Is there some rule that I can't reference purely on the primary key?

Comment: Please show `SHOW CREATE db` from the database, or `DESCRIBE db`.

Comment: is `f_index` is `form_index` or `f_index` as you are telling in your question?

Comment: Don't ever use direct $_POST values for DB query!!!

Comment: Woah didn't even notice `index`, nice work below. Also once it works, be sure to escape the query properly.

Comment: @Svetlio This is a trusted source that is behind quite a few locked doors. As well, the situation is unique that would allow for this type.

Comment: @Christopher if your Post send just 1 ' it will break your code.. It doesn't matter if its trusted you must sanitize your queries always..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index` is reserved word in mysql, you can't directly use it as column name, you have to use `` ` `` around column name for using these kind of reserved words.

```
$query = "UPDATE db SET `this`='$_POST[f_that]',`this2`='$_POST[f_that2]' 
WHERE `index`='$_POST[f_index]'";
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!! I'll mark it as an answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @Yogesh, how do you show backstick  around the `index`. i could not show it

Comment: @Yogesh, thanks , but i can not generate it. perhaps your editor have more options

Answer (score 0):

`index` is reserved word, you should change it or use back stick like below

```
`index`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change column name for `index`. It is treating as a keyword in your query.